# Is it possible to use RestKit to store local data in Core data without network communication

Tags: objective-c, core-data, restkit, restkit-0.20

Is it possible to use RestKit to store local data in Core data?

The current project uses Restkit to download and update info in Core Data, I would like to store some other data to local coredata without network communication. Do I have to create a new data model or I can add new entities to current data model which is managed by restkit? If I can use current coredata model, can I use persistentStoreCoordinator from restkit or I have to create my own persistentStoreCoordinator and ManagedObjectContext?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the same data model. You should ask the RK managed object store for the appropriate context (main thread or new depending on what you're doing).